# Как сделать галерею превью слайдера?

Tags: html, jquery, css

Есть задача - сверстать галерею товаров, чтобы по клику на превью, она отображалась в [image: введите сюда описание изображения]окне.

Конечно, можно использовать готовое решение в виде плагина, но не хочу лишний раз нагружать сайт т.к. я уже использовал слайдер в проекте http://responsiveslides.com/ . Можно ли реализовать вывод превью на основе этого слайдера? Или же просто на jquery...
Буду очень благодарен за помощь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если что-то простое, то например так:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.slide__link').on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log('Slide show prew On click! \n');

  var $this = $(this),
      item = $this.closest('.slide__item'),
      wrap = $this.closest('.slideShow'),
      gap = wrap.find('.slide__gap'),
      itemPath = $this.find('img').attr('src'),
      dur = 500;

  if(!item.hasClass('activSl')){
    item.addClass('.activSl').siblings().removeClass('activSl');
    gap.find('img').fadeOut(dur, function(){
      $(this).attr('src', itemPath).fadeIn(dur);
    });
  }   

});
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.slideShow {
 max-width: 700px;
 width: 100%;
 margin: 20px auto;
}
.slide__list {
 margin: 2px 0;
}
.slide__item {
 width: 25%;
 padding: 1px;
 position: relative;
    display: block;
    float: left;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}

.slide__item:hover {
  border: 1px solid #333;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slideShow">
  <div class="slide__gap">
    <img src="http://eurozabor.kharkov.ua/edit/uploads/page/12/0ca447203ef7436e9f36e0767644fa0d.png" alt="">
  </div>

  <ul class="slide__list flex-row">
    <li class="slide__item">
      <a href="#" class="slide__link">
        <img src="http://eurozabor.kharkov.ua/edit/uploads/page/12/0ca447203ef7436e9f36e0767644fa0d.png" alt="">
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="slide__item">
      <a href="#" class="slide__link">
        <img src="http://eurozabor.kharkov.ua/edit/uploads/page/12/0ca447203ef7436e9f36e0767644fa0d.png" alt="">
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="slide__item">
      <a href="#" class="slide__link">
        <img src="http://eurozabor.kharkov.ua/edit/uploads/page/12/0ca447203ef7436e9f36e0767644fa0d.png" alt="">
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="slide__item">
      <a href="#" class="slide__link">
        <img src="http://eurozabor.kharkov.ua/edit/uploads/page/12/0ca447203ef7436e9f36e0767644fa0d.png" alt="">
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: Спасибо. Только вот когда вставляю в свой файл.js, в $(document).ready(function() , он не работает.
Если вставляю в тело html в теги <script> - работает. Не подскажите, в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: @Александр, даже не знаю! У меня с `$(document).ready` в отдельном main.js файле и работает. Проверьте, чтобы jquery.js был подключен.
` html код (слайдшоу) --> jquery.js --> ваш.js --> `